# comunicacion serial convierte char a caracter extraño

Tags: c++, arduino

Trato de hacer un programa que al recibir la letra "a" por la comunicacion serial prenda un led y al recibir la letra "b", prenda pues otro led xd...

### Problema

primero que todo, para que entiendan de lo que hablo, este es el código:

```
#define pinGreen 3
#define pinRed 5

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(pinGreen, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pinRed, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0){
      char received;
      received = (char) Serial.read();
      convertToStatus(convertToStatus);
  }
  delay(500);
}

void convertToStatus(char chr){
  Serial.println(chr);
  if(chr == "a"){
    digitalWrite(pinRed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinGreen, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }else if(chr == "b"){
    digitalWrite(pinGreen, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pinRed, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

pasa que al enviar la letra "a" por ejemplo, no entra en el if correspondiente a esa letra, y pues hice una prueba para ver que era lo que le pasaba a la funcion, y me di cuenta que por una razón que desconozco, en vez de pasar la letra "a", pasaba el caracter: "^", y no se pq pasa esto, porfavor si alguien me puede ayudar plis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dos errores:

La función `convertToStatus` requiere un `char` como parámetro y tú le pasas una función.

La llamada correcta es:

```
convertToStatus(received);
```

En C, las constantes de caracter se escriben entre comillas simples, por lo que la comparación correcta es

```
  if(chr == 'a'){
  ...
  } else if(chr == 'b') {
```

Con esos dos cambios ya funciona.